# Event registration website...

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have the following website that I am building and I have gotten a bit stuck.
http://www.eventslee.com/personal_event.php?eid=1

Under the ticket details there is a list of different ticket types. These tickets are from mysql and will change depending on what the event creator adds.

What I need is for people to be able to pick a quantity for multiple tickets at once and then click register and then it goes to a purchase screen. At the purchase screen it will display the ticket types they have chosen with the quantity next to them.

For example if they pick quantity = 2 for test ticket2 then on the next page it will come up test ticket2 quantity x 2. If you don't know what I am asking please let me know.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the question because I didn't see any question yet!

Comment: what is your code? can attach here?

Comment: I see **"purchase"** and `mysql_*` --- (gulp) --- *Plus*, your site (*as it stands*) is open to "you know what". It's time for you to look into prepared statements or PDO before purchasing can be done; **seriously**.

Comment: the site as it stands is just the start...very quickly thrown together and will make sure it isn't open to "you know what" before launching it.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use something like this in your HTML:

```
<select name="numberOfTickets">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

and then once the form is submitted, e.g. with method="POST", access the chosen value using

```
$numberOfTickets = $_POST['numberOfTickets'];
```